# DevIL PNG format for display in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, devil, gldrawpixels

I'm doing some pixel work in OpenGL, and all was going well until I had to load a PNG.  I found a thing called 'DevIL', and followed an example I found.  It does display something, but it's just kind of a random rainbow.  I'm doing it right as far as I can tell; I output the data to a text file to check it.  I tried some other libraries, but building them is a little beyond my capabilities.  Here's my setup:

```
((In global scope))
unsigned char pixels[160000*3];
ILubyte * bytes  ;

((Main))
ilInit();

ilLoadImage( "test.png" ) ;

size = ilGetInteger( IL_IMAGE_SIZE_OF_DATA ) ;

bytes = ilGetData() ;
```

And here's my drawing routine:

```
//Color the screen all pretty
for(int i=0;i<160000*3;)
{   
    pixels[i] = a;
    i++;
    pixels[i] = b;
    i++;
    pixels[i] = c;
    i++;
}   

//Break the png
for( int i = 0 ; i < size;)
{
    if(bytes[i+3] != 255)
    {   i+=4;
            continue;   }

    pixels[i] = bytes[i];
    i++;
    pixels[i] = bytes[i];
    i++;
    pixels[i] = bytes[i];
    i++;
    i++;
}

glDrawPixels(
    400,
    300,
    GL_RGB,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    pixels
    );
```

I know the alignment is wrong; I'll fix that later.  The problem is the colors are totally not right

P.S.  I know you're supposed to use textured quads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG is a compressed format. Seems like ilGetData returns pointer to a compressed data. To get decoded image use ilCopyPixels.

Comment: Thanks, the color is correct, but I can't seem to get the alpha to display properly, even though I made sure everything was RGBA.  Also, is there a way to convert the data so I can display it with a for loop?

Comment: Nevermind, got it working, just overlooked some details, thanks :)